# How to align textView on layout center without conflict with other view?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I have an issue trying align textView to the center of layout: when I try to do this - **it has a conflict with a button on the left** - if text is too long - it become hidden under the button. Text length can be very different and I need it in the center of layout but not under/on the button.

Here is the xml file of activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_content_action_bar_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@color/colorBlue"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/item_content_title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:id="@+id/item_content_back_button"
            android:background="@drawable/back_button_selector"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/item_content_scroll_view"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="125dp"
                    android:id="@+id/item_content_image"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_no_thumbnail"
                    android:maxHeight="125dp"
                    android:maxWidth="125dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/item_content_subtitle"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Subtitle"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/item_content_image"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_content_image"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/item_content_image"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/item_content_pubdate"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Date"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/item_content_subtitle"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/item_content_subtitle"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/item_content_subtitle"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/item_content_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="blabla"
                android:layout_below="@+id/item_content_pubdate"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/item_content_pubdate"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your xml contains error

Answer (score 1):

Try using **LinearLayout with layout-weight** for this to avoid conflict. Change your first relativelayout to below one

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_content_action_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/_white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="7">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/item_content_back_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@drawable/chemist" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_content_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Inform me if having problems.@Igor Dotsenko

Answer (score 0):

Change Your `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` and use `android:layout_weight` attribute of layout to do this.

```
<LinearLayout

           android:id="@+id/item_content_action_bar_layout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="@color/_white"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:padding="10dp"
           android:weightSum="1"           
            >

            <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/item_content_back_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"            
            android:background="@drawable/chemist" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/item_content_title"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:autoText="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the layout_gravity of the textview ***item_content_title*** as "*center_horizontal*".

And add `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_content_title"` under the ImageButton ***item_content_back_button***.

Hope it was what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Your Action bar layout has to be like this-

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_content_action_bar_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@color/colorBlue"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:id="@+id/item_content_back_button"
            android:background="@drawable/back_button_selector"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
       <TextView
            android:toRightOf="@id/item_content_back_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/item_content_title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```